# Are fixed mobile headers and footers that disappear and reappear on tap really useful?

Tags: interaction-design, mobile, design-patterns, touch-screen, fixed-header

[These fixed mobile **headers and footers**](http://view.jquerymobile.com/master/demos/widgets/fixed-toolbars/) disappear and reappear on click / tap using jQuery Mobile's data-tap-toggle which is on by default. How useful are they?

**Pro:** More content is available when they disappear.

**Con:** Users not familiar with this pattern may panic, and crucial functions in these headers / footers might be lost forever.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They are useful **during pure media consumption** like viewing images, videos, etc.

Regarding the issue of educating the user of their usage: the current standard implementation is quite good enough. **Display the controls and additional data when opening the content and then remove them after a few seconds.** This tells the user there is all the other information (controls, tags, etc.) available and it disappeared. The first reaction when a person sees this is touch the screen, and, viola! They appear back and the user is trained! MAGIC!

This is similar to the **onboarding process** that has been tried and tested by game designers since decades. You are either showing the path of the entire level before the game begins, or you can see a sneak peek of some ability (jumping, ducking, etc.) right before you need to use it. **Show the capability and the user will learn by watching and experimenting.**